# The device must have a passcode set in order to allow this operation (0xE8003FFE)

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, ip-address, xcode, ipad

I want to connect iPad from Xcode using connect via IP Address (WIFI). I did not configure passcode in iPad but iPad is asking to set passcode while connecting from Xcode. Can you please let me know how to connect iPad from Xcode using WIFI without set passcode in iPad ?

Comment: Why not just add a passcode?

Comment: Appium will ask passcode while running test script in real iPad device but I cannot enter passcode manually each and every time. I am trying to execute appium test script in WIFI mode without entering passcode.

Comment: if it says the device must have a passcode set, then that's what you need to do.

Comment: I am using iPad for automation testing and the device is available in remote location. I cannot connect iPad remotely and enter password.

Comment: @poovaraj Did you ever figure out the solution to this problem. I am facing the exact problem.

Comment: @Prakhar : I did get solution for this

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @poovaraj Could you tell me the solution ?

Comment: I didn't get solution till now